# Resizing images on the fly or doing it up front?

Tags: java, image, jakarta-ee, caching

I am creating a web service that will be able to serve images that users uploads as part of other resources to the server.

The client application will be smart phones and tablets, but since I don't know what will be the next thing other devices may be supported in the future as well.

Serving a high resolution 2000px x 2000px to a device with a low resolution isn't necassary so based on a parameter in the request I want to be able to:

a) Generate a picture of the wanted size like this: `/static/1234?width=300&height=300`
b) Get a pre processed image that is resized up front to a fixed set of sizes: `/static/1234?size=small`

Of course, option `a` is more flexible but it is also more demanding on the server. If I should go with this option there must be a cache mechanism that sees if there is an image with that size already made.

I am using JackRabbit (a content repository) to save the images. For the cache would you just save the cached image in the file system and hold a map of the file names in memory, or are there libraries that is popular to use for this purpose?

Or would I be better off with option `b`?

Comment: Generally, I would think that pre-generating a series of scaled images up-front would be less expensive then trying to do it at run time. he only issue you would need to consider is the amount of disk space this would require, but it would be faster and generally less CPU intensive to server the images if they were pre-rendered. But there might be other considerations that I haven't thought of...

Comment: If you can afford the storage space, and if there are a limited number of sizes needed, pre-scaling your "thumbnail" images would be more efficient.

You may want a cache mechanism even so,  depending on how many images, how many distinct sizes, and how many users you're talking about, just to keep the most-used images in memory rather than always fetching them from file.

Comment: @keshlam Are there any common cache libraries for this?

Comment: @Andreas Probably; I haven't had reason to go looking for them, though, so I can't recommend one in specific. I think the Websphere server has mechanisms for this but I haven't had my fingers in that end of the code so I can't vouch for it. Should be a fairly standard "keep the N most-used/most-recently-used" kind of logic, I would expect.

Comment: @keshlam Yeah, it shouldn't be hard to implement a basic cache.